# Best Approach to show/hide elements within a certain date range

Tags: javascript, jquery

Usecase:

I have a list of about 1000 Items and would like to have a "date range filter" to show/hide elements which are in between the 2 dates given.

How would you go about this?

I am thinking about applying a selector with the "date" or "timestamp" to each element and loop over all elements onChange of the Datepicker Range.

Does this make sense to you and maybe anyone has an example for this? 
My brain is in freeze mode currently and I could use some inspiration ...

Comment: Are you using any javascript frameworks or native+jquery?

Comment: project uses jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I ended up using:

HTML:

```
<li id="xxx" rel="<?=strtotime($row['date'])?>">
    some content
</li>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    //range defined by datepicker

    $(".range").change(function(e){
        var tfrom = new Date($('#from').val()).getTime() / 1000;
        var tto =  new Date('$('#to').val()).getTime() / 1000;

        $('li').filter(function(){
            var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
            var flag = false;

            if( rel > tto || rel < tfrom ){
                flag = true;
            }
            return flag;
        }).hide();
    });
});     
</script>
```

Works exaclty as it should . thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Is better to use the "filter" function.

You can define your own return values avoiding to use a loop.

```js
$(function() {
    $("div[id]").filter(function(){
      var code = +$(this).prop("id").split("_")[1];
      var flag = false;
      
      if( code > 4 ){
        flag = true;
      }
      
      return flag;
    }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test_1">1<div>
<div id="test_2">2<div>
<div id="test_3">3<div>
<div id="test_4">4<div>
<div id="test_5">5<div>
<div id="test_6">6<div>
```

Comment: I like this approach.

I will go for id="T_1193050938" (instead of using ="D2007-10-27") and run the filter onChange of the daterange selctor.

So when a date range is selected modify date into timestamp and filter each element based on the current timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use `VueJs` (or another framework like `AngularJs` etc). With `v-if` directive it should be a very easy implementation.

Because there is no support for `vueJs` in the code snippet, I am writing here a working example. `2017-03-03` && `2018-03-3` are just random dates for demonstration purposes. You can really make a loop using `vueJs` and handle all 1000 elements in 10 lines of code

```
# html
<div id="app">
  <span v-if="'2017-03-03' >= dateFrom && '2017-03-03' <= dateTo">
    You see me
  </span>
  <span v-if="'2018-03-03' >= dateFrom && '2018-03-03' <= dateTo">
    Not see me
  </span>
</div>

# vueJs
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    dateFrom: '2017-01-01',
    dateTo: '2017-01-01'
  }
})
```

Of course you need to change the implementation using some computed properties, but this is enough to open the way.

> You can find information about the conditional rendering at this [page](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)
>
> You can find information about the list rendering [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html)

I hope it helps and make sense to you!